GA4 Report to Track Daily Free Quote Form Submissions by Region and Value
I have a custom event in GA4 called free_quote_form_submission that includes the following parameters:

form_location: Indicates the region of the submission (either "US" or
"AU").
value: This is based on a specific field selection, which can
be either 15 or 250.

I want to see a daily breakdown of submissions, categorized by each permutation of these parameters:
Region (US or AU)
Value (15 or 250)
In other words, I’d like to view, per day, the total number of submissions for each of these combinations:



form_location
15
250




US
2
4


AU
1
2



I've tried building this report in GA4, but I can only seem to get the total event count without seeing each permutation.
Any advice on setting up a report or any alternative way to visualize this data in GA4 (or other platform) would be greatly appreciated!


Go to GA4 and open Explorations.
Create a new report of the Free Form type.
In the Dimensions section, add the form_location and value parameters, as well as the date.
In the Metrics section, select the event count metric.
Drag form_location, value, and date to column, row, and filters to create the desired breakdown.

And for visualization, the easiest option is Google Data Studio.
